# Is the Larmor precession of $s$-orbital electrons constant, heedless of additional electronic orbitals as they get added from one element to another?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Understanding how the frequency required in NMR changes from element to element, even if all of them depend on the Larmor precession of the proton, I was wondering if they same applied to electron shells or if not applicable, energy levels, such as the ground state.